# Issue with mongo query to find record based on two conditions for a field

Tags: javascript, json, mongodb, mongoose, database

I have a collection with a particular field status.I want to query collection to find the records which have status="error" or "incomplete".I tried this

```
collectioname.find({"status":" 'error'||'incomplete' "})
```

But didnt worked.can some one help quickly.Thanks!!!